# How to authenticate a request with htpasswd in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, .htpasswd

I am trying to fetch a rss feed from our staging site and at present it has htpasswd security on it.

I have tied using the format:

```
http://username:password@url.com
```

This works on the browser but when I try to do this with nodejs it fails.

Could you tell me what is the right way to do this with node.js.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

app.js

```
var request = require('request');

request.get('http://url.com', callback).auth('username', 'password', false);

function callback(err, response, body) {
  console.log(body);
}
```

terminal:

```
npm install request
node app.js
```

document: https://github.com/mikeal/request